# Django: Forloop Counter 0 divisible by 3 not working properly

Tags: django, django-templates

**PLATFORM**: Django

**Problem**
When using {% forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %} it doesn't seem to properly divide out? I can't quite tell what's going on.

**Goal**
Display an Avery HTML template with pre-populated info from the database. 3 column table with variable rows.

**Code**

```html
<table>
    {% for job in jobsite %}
        {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}<tr>{% endif %}

        <td>{{ job.name }}<br/>{{ job.address }}<br/>{{ job.address_2 }}{% if job.address_2 %}<br/>{% endif %}{{ job.city }}, {{ job.state }} {{ job.zip }}</td>

        {% if forloop.counter < 3 %}
            <td class="spacer" rowspan="0">&nbsp;</td>
        {% endif %}

        {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 or forloop.last %}<tr>{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

**Why is this failing?**
[image: What's going on here?]

**Additional Info**
I can get close if I change the code around to the following. The problem then becomes that counter 2 is blank. If I fill in data, it's duplicated (row 1 column 2, row 1 column 3):

```html
<table>
    <tr>
    {% for job in jobsite %}
        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}</tr><tr>{% endif %}

        <td>{{ job.name }}<br/>{{ job.address }}<br/>{{ job.address_2 }}{% if job.address_2 %}<br/>{% endif %}{{ job.city }}, {{ job.state }} {{ job.zip }}</td>

        {% if forloop.counter < 3 %}
            <td class="spacer" rowspan="0">&nbsp;</td>
        {% endif %}

        {% if forloop.counter == 2 %}
            <td></td>
{#            <td>{{ job.name }}<br/>{{ job.address }}<br/>{{ job.city }}, {{ job.state }} {{ job.zip }}</td>#}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

**Close to the desired display**
[image: Close to right]

Comment: `counter0` counts `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, so it means the first loop already is `True`, whereas `.count` counts `1`, `2`, `3`, so then the third one is the first where the condition is true...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've gathered that much, but changing it to 4 presents 4 columns in rows 2+ (when not 0 based). How would you suggest I rearrange the code?

Comment: Exactly what is the `spacer` supposed to do?

Comment: The spacer puts in a blank "column" that accounts for the gap between labels horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

> Problem When using `{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}` it doesn't seem to properly divide out? I can't quite tell what's going on.

The `forloop.counter0` will count with `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, …. This means that the *first* cycle will already satisfy the condition, since `0` is dividably by `3` (and by any number), so it will already apply the "split logic" for the first cycle. `forloop.counter` on the other hand will count with `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, … so the first iteration where it will add a line is the third one.

You can work with:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    {% for job in jobsite %}
        <td>{{ job.name }}<br/>{{ job.address }}<br/>{{ job.address_2 }}{% if job.address_2 %}<br/>{% endif %}{{ job.city }}, {{ job.state }} {{ job.zip }}</td>
        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 and not forloop.last %}
            </tr><tr>
        {% elif not forloop.last %}
            <td class="spacer" rowspan="0">&nbsp;</td>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: While on the surface this looks like it should work, it seems to present a staggered view instead.

Comment: @beach_it: did you add the `<tr>` and `</tr>` before and after the loop, and only add a `</tr><tr>` in the `{% if ... %}` *after* the `<td>...</td>` part?

Comment: Yes. Here's a screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/1yBqOlc

Comment: @beach_it: is there a loop, *outside* the `for job in jobsite`?

Comment: Nope. Here's the codebase. https://github.com/varlenthegray/wcadmin/blob/dev/jobsite/templates/jobsite/address_labels.html

Comment: @beach_it: but you should omit the `if forloop.counter <= 3` logic. The logic in the answer should be sufficient for the entire loop (including the spacers).

Comment: Ah, sorry for the extraneous if statement. I'm trying to figure out another way to work around this. I agree - it should work, but removing the ```if <= 3``` should work, but it doesn't. It presents the staggered view as seen earlier.

Comment: Even simplifying the code to the following doesn't seem to present as expected:

`
{% for job in jobsite %}
        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}<tr>{% endif %}

        <td>{{ job.name }}<br/>{{ job.address }}<br/>{{ job.address_2 }}{% if job.address_2 %}<br/>{% endif %}{{ job.city }}, {{ job.state }} {{ job.zip }}</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>

        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}</tr>{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
`

Comment: @beach_it: part of it is because you open an extra `<tr>`, in the `{% else %}` clause, but that is not necessary. The `{% if ... %}` in the answer simply closes a row, and opens a new one if we reached the end of the row.

Comment: @beach_it: please simply use it as in the answer, so *without* all the extra `{% if ... %}`s and modified HTML...

Comment: I've updated the git with the latest code change that I believe "should" work, but it doesn't. 

https://imgur.com/a/GeAeLoa

https://github.com/varlenthegray/wcadmin/blob/dev/jobsite/templates/jobsite/address_labels.html

Comment: @beach_it: this will not, since the `<tr>` is not opened for the first items, you only open a `<tr>` for the third item, and then closes that again... Why is it so hard to simply copy the answer verbatim?

Comment: This is the result of verbatim copy:

https://imgur.com/a/Q394T2R

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a solution to this specific challenge, however I redesigned it primarily relying on CSS instead of table layout. Code as follows "solves" the challenge.

```html
{% for job in jobsite %}
    <div class="address-label">{{ job.name }}<br/>{{ job.address }}<br/>{{ job.address_2 }}{% if job.address_2 %}<br/>{% endif %}{{ job.city }}, {{ job.state }} {{ job.zip }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```